# A question about Helium spectrum

Tags: atomic-physics, spectroscopy, hydrogen, binding-energy, ionization-energy

I'm starting to read about two-electron atoms from physics of atoms and molecules by Bransden.

Analyzing Helium spectrum I noticed that the energy of $He^+(1s)+e^-$ is greater than the energy of He, where the energy of $He^+(1s)+e^-$ is calculated using the $E_n$'s formula of hydrogenic atom with Z=2 (-2.0 a.u.). Obviously in order to obtain $He^+(1s)+e^-$ I have to excite He, so it is natural that the energy of $He^+(1s)+e^-$ is bigger that energy of He. But how is it possible that an atom with Z=2 when it has 1 electron this is *less bound* and when it has 2 electrons these are *more bound*? It appears to me that the one-electron should be *more bound* because the nuclear charge is Z=2 and there aren't repulsive effects.

Sorry for bad English and thanks you all.

Comment: <I have to excite He, so it is natural that the energy of He+(1s)+e− is bigger that energy of He.> ..why you  say that as for excitation you must have put in work/energy and it will get less bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helium has two electrons. So you have to be careful *which* ionisation energy you are talking about. If it's the one to remove the *first*, the *second*, or *all* electrons.

The first ionisation energy is $ 24.59 \, eV $, experimentally. This makes it go from $He$ to $He^+ + e^-$.

The second ionsation energy is $54.42 \, eV$, which can be calculated theoretically because the Helium *ion* is a hydrogenic atom. This makes it go from $He^+$ to $He^{++} + 2e^-$.

So you see that it is **easier** to remove the first electron, when you start from a 2 electron situation. This is because the second electron is more loosely bound to the nucleus, since the nuclear charge $Z$ is shielded by the first electron and becomes an effective $Z_{eff} < 2$.

When you solve the Helium atom, you treat the electron-electron repulsion as a pertubration. 
 You start with the energy of the second electron to be $-54.42\, eV$ (from the hydrogenic atom formula) and you add the postive repulsive energy that it gets from $e-e$ interaction. This gives you an energy of $-24.39 \, eV$, which means you have to provide $24.39 \, eV$ in order to *free* (ionise) the first electron.